# Dystopian Arthouse film about a man making a robot in a dystopian destroyed city

Tags: story-identification, movie, dystopia

I found a movie a while ago that I just can not remember the name of.

It was centered around a man in a dystopian destroyed city who was making a robot in his basement. He makes the robot look like him and leaves it locked in the house. There are some scenes where the robot plays classical music on his piano.

The man starts sending the robot out to the grocery store to collect the food, and it saves the woman who works there from a burglar. The man realises that he can pretend to be his robot and get with the girl. He then takes the woman into his house, gets her pregnant and turns the robot off and stashes him in the basement.

This movie may be in a different language too. I remember it looking very drab, brown, and almost war-torn Germany.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question). Also, where did you 'find' this film?

Comment: elements of this remind me of the film Hardware from 1990 It has robots being built and an underground dystopian setting but I wouldn't say its an exact match.  anyway check out the trailer here and see if its the one... but I wouldn't say its an exact match.

Answer (score 6):

This is a strange little movie called [*Puzzlehead*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puzzlehead) from 2005.

> Walter, a scientist living in a dark world where technology has been outlawed, secretly works to create a self-aware android in his own likeness. This android, named Puzzlehead by Walter, acts as the scientist's companion and his connection to the outside world; all the time developing his own personality and self-awareness in the manner of a learning child. The android and his maker turn against one another when Puzzlehead pursues Julia, a woman who does not know Walter has feelings for her.

Julia works in a grocery store and Puzzlehead saves her from a burglar. And Puzzlehead plays the piano (more like a harpsichord, I think). Here's the trailer: